# Error while pulling kafka jks certificates from hdfs (trying with s3 as well) in spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am Running spark in cluster mode which is giving error as

```
ERROR SslEngineBuilder: Modification time of key store could not be obtained: hdfs://ip:port/user/hadoop/jks/kafka.client.truststore.jks
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: hdfs:/ip:port/user/hadoop/jks/kafka.client.truststore.jks
```

I ran below command and verified that `jks` files are present at the location.

```bash
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://ip:port/user/hadoop/\<folder1\>
```

I have written below code to connect to kafka in spark project.

Spark Code:

```scala
sparkSession.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", )
.option("subscribe", )
...
.option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", "pswd")
.option("kafka.ssl.key.password", "pswrd"))      
.option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location","hdfs:///node:port/user/hadoop/\<folder1\>/kafka.client.truststore.jks")
.option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", "hdfs:///node:port/user/hadoop/\<folder1\>/kafka.client.keystore.jks")
```

1. Please suggest what is missing?
2. How to achieve the same with `jks` file in s3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `--files s3a://...` (or with `hdfs`) on your `spark-submit` option, or use `spark.files` option in the built session.

Then you can refer to those files by name directly (not with the full path), as they are looked up by relative path to the Spark executor.

For reading from S3, you'll also need to (securely) define your S3 access keys (i.e. not as plaintext in your Spark code).  Use an `hdfs-site.xml` resource file.

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer , Thank you so much! files are accessible now. But not able to connect to kafka broker: Error :-- 
`WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-x-xx-driver-0] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
Messages are not getting consumed.`

Comment: That could just be a generic network issue like firewall, etc denying connection, nothing to do with Spark. SSH to any of your Spark executors and simply run Kafka CLI tools directly to debug

Comment: Yes, its working now. Spark executor was not whitelisted. Thanks for your support! @OneCricketeer